# how can i display all of the results from my table where the column (date and time) has the the same date and time

Tags: php, mysql

You see in my table in the column (date and time) : i have multipes same result  date and time.
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7FuS.png]

1. how can i display all of the results from my table where the column (date and time) has the the  same date and time.
2. how can i count in every table the result of the column price that has the same date and time.

This is my php code:

```
<tabl>
<?php
    function connectDb($username,$password,$hostname,$dbname)
    {
       $conn=mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password") or die(mysql_error());
       $db=mysql_select_db("$dbname",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    connectDb('root','root','localhost','vetemenstdb');
    // end connect db

    // start display result
    function select()
    {
        $tableName = 'venteJour';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
        $sql   = mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            $id           = $row['id'];
            $Name         = $row['nomDuProduit'];
            $price        = $row['PrixVenteFinal'];
            $quantity     = $row['QuantityVendue'];
            $dateAndTime  = $row['dateAndTime'];
            echo"
                <tr>
                    <td>$id</td>
                    <td>$Name</td>
                    <td>$price</td>
                    <td>$quantity</td>
                    <td>$dateAndTime</td>
                </tr>";
        }

    }
    select();
    //end display result
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Please dont use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated. Consider moving to `mysqli_*`

Comment: first of all the `mysql` extension is deprecated and already has been removed in PHP 7+;

Comment: yes i know that thanks bro

Comment: If you know that why are you still using it? There's a reason you're being shamed here. This code is extremely risky.

Comment: this is not for a webste..it's just for a software computer..and i like when i use the old version of php mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean has the same date and time?

```
Select DISTINCT dateAndTime from tablename
```

After doing the same queries in other tables you simply

```
if ($dateAndTime1 != $dateAndTime2) 
       return false;
```

or you could use

```
array_intersect($array1, $array2)
```

if you don't want to sort arrays but just want to check equality regardless of value order use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Updated:

```
select dateandtime, count(*) as c from table
group by dateandtime having c > 1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer: i create now a software of selling and when a custumer buy ..he can buy a lot of things..so when i ansert this thing in my database i insert them with the same date and time..so i want to just display  every same result that has the same date and time in a a defferen table

Comment: check it out was this the result you wanted

Comment: i did not understand your first answer..please i'm not a professional..so try to give me a solution writing step by step: please focus with me: i wont something like that : select *  from tablename where dateAndTime are equals...but put every same results in a different tables....for exmple in my table in the photo..i want to put the first 3 result in a table..after..i put the second2 result in  auther table...after i put the third 2 results in an auther table..

Comment: can you please show me how the result is needed ? comment after your done

Comment: yes i find a beautifull result but is difficult   : $query = "SELECT PrixVenteFinal as PrixVenteFinal, dateAndTime,date, time FROM venteJour GROUP BY time HAVING(date) ='$ajaxDate' ORDER BY dateAndTime asc";     it's my varriable in the query so try to make your varriables

Comment: @NassimNasri tell me